# Deeply extract all used symbols from a hash of nested symbols in an array

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hash of symbols like this:

```
{
  a: {
    b: :c,
    d: {
      e: :f
    }
  },
  g: :h
}
```

I want to build an array that contains all symbols used in the hash, both keys and values, in any order. For the example above:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g, :h]
```

Is there any simple, fast and ruby-friendly way to do this?

I'm doing this with a recursive function that sums `hash.keys` with `hash.values`, and finally applies `flatten` to the result.

```
def all_keys(hash)
  hash.keys + hash.values.map { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) ? all_keys(e) : e }
end
```

Comment: If `h` is your hash, a quick and dirty would be `h.to_s.scan /:[a-z]\w*/
 => [":a", ":b", ":c", ":d", ":e", ":f", ":g", ":h"] `.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some notes:

- The flattening should be performed where the non-desired nesting is being introduced, not later. Use `flat_map` instead of `map`:
- Why `e` for the value name instead of `v`?

I'd write:

```
def all_keys(hash)
  hash.keys + hash.values.flat_map { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? all_keys(v) : [v] }
end
```

Another way to do it, slightly shorter, is to iterate directly the pairs. Pick the one which is more declarative to you:

```
def all_keys(hash)
  hash.flat_map { |k, v| [k] + (v.is_a?(Hash) ? all_keys(v) : [v]) }
end
```